# почему неправильно выводится массив (не переходит к следующей строке, бесконечно меняются только столбцы)

Tags: c, указатели, динамические-массивы

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *f_out, *f_in;
double *a;
int i,j;

void output_0(int n, int m, double A[n][m]){
    int i,j;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for (j=1; j<=m; j++){
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            A[i][j] = (float)1/(i+j);
            printf ("%f\n", A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void output_1(int n, int m, double A[n][m]){
    int i,j;
    f_out = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<m; j++){
            A[i][j] = (float)1/(i+j);
            fprintf(f_out, "a[%d][%d] = %f\n", i,j, A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, int** argv){
    int in, out, next, n, m;
    system("chcp 1251");

    do{
        printf("input from console - 0 or from file - 1? ");
        scanf ("%d", &in);
        printf("output from console - 0 or from file - 1? ");
        scanf("%d", &out);

        if (in ==0){
                printf("Введите количество строк: ");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                printf("Введите количество столбцов: ");
                scanf("%d", &m);
        } else if (in == 1){
                f_in = fopen("in.txt", "r");
                fscanf(f_in, "%d, %d", &n, &m);
        } else {
                printf("ОШИБКА!");
        }

        a = (double*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));

        if (out == 0){
                output_0(n,m,a);
        } else if (out == 1){
                output_1(n,m,a);
        } else {
                printf("ОШИБКА!");
        }
        printf("\n\nNEXT - 1, EXIT - 0? ");
        scanf("%d", &next);

    } while (next !=0);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы объявили указатель типа `double *`.

```
double *a;
//...
a = (double*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));
```

Поэтому вы не можете использовать его как аргумент для функции, соответствующий параметр которой имеет тип `double ( * )[m]` (то есть типы `double *` и `double ( * )[m]` не совместимы)

```
void output_0(int n, int m, double A[n][m]){
    int i,j;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for (j=1; j<=m; j++){
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            A[i][j] = (float)1/(i+j);
            printf ("%f\n", A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

и использовать выражения вида `A[i][j]`.

К тому же индексация массивов в C начинается с 0.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как можно организовать работу с динамически выделяемым двумерным массивом переменной длины.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f( int n, int m, double a[n][m] )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m; j++ ) 
        {
            a[i][j] = i * m + j;
            printf( "%4.1f ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int n, m;

    scanf( "%d %d", &n, &m );

    double ( *a )[m] = malloc( sizeof( double[n][m] ) );

    f( n, m, a );

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Если ввести числа `5` и `6`, то вывод может выглядеть как

```
 0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0 
 6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0 11.0 
12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 17.0 
18.0 19.0 20.0 21.0 22.0 23.0 
24.0 25.0 26.0 27.0 28.0 29.0
```

Обратите внимание, что заголовок `<malloc.h>` не является стандартным заголовком.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, теперь все работает!